# Cyclic startup problems (black screen -> superblock checksum wrong -> kernel panic after e2fsck -> ok startup -> black screen -> ...)

Tags: boot, filesystem, startup

I have these problems on every boot. Basically, the booting my system acts like a state machine. The first state is booting into a black screen. I'm forced to power the PC off. After this, the next boot results in e2fsck detecting a problem with the superblock checksum as shown below.

[image]

As shown, I run an `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda11 -y`

The result of this is the following - directories, free inodes counts wrong => file system modified (and the values are identical on every startup):

[image]

I type `exit` after this, and get this kernel panic message:

[image]

This forces me to power off the PC again, however the next boot works just fine and I get into the system.

Unfortunately the moment I turn the PC off and want to boot again, I revert back to the first state, basically forcing me to go through this whole procedure every time I want to boot. How can I fix this permanently? Maybe this could somehow be related to the fact that I have a hybrid hard drive?

Comment: Posting as a comment because I can only guess. Probably it's an hardware failure of your disk. The `fsck` somewhat fixes it but as soon as your using your system the errors appears again, preventing the next boot to go through cleanly and then forcing you to use `fsck` again.

Comment: As a quick test, you can try to force an automatic `fsck` on next boot via `sudo touch /root/forcefsck`